# Slow performance Input event in contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, performance, ecmascript-6

I have a DIV which has contenteditable attribute and I am running 70 lines of JavaScript code on [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) but when I try to type fast. The **JavaScript code is very slow** and the results don't show/update in the UI as quickly as expected.

What I am doing in the JavaScript is in the input event:
I am getting the textcontent of the DIV with `contenteditable` attribute and then changing it to array with `split()` function and then, by using a for loop, I am comparing the array values with other array. If the value matches I create a SPAN with `textContent` set as the current value from that `contenteditable` DIV and then put it in an `spanArray` array. Then I'm appending all those SPANs into the  `contenteditable` DIV and setting the caret at the end.

How to optimize the code so that the type speed / performance is not affected by the JavaScript's heavy for loops seen in the below example?

Here is the code I got so far:

```js
const mainDiv = document.querySelector("#mainDiv");
const placeHolderDiv = document.querySelector("#placeholder");
let placeHolder = "";
let placeHolderArr;

fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
  .then((data) => {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    for (let quote = 0; quote < 10; quote++) {
      placeHolder += result[quote].text;
      placeHolderArr = placeHolder.split(" ");
      placeHolderDiv.textContent = placeHolder;
    }
  });

mainDiv.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  let spanArr = [];
  const mainDivArr = mainDiv.textContent.split(" ");
  let num = 0;
  if (e.code !== "Space") {
    for (let i of mainDivArr) {
      if (placeHolderArr[num].trim() === mainDivArr[num].trim()) {
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.textContent = mainDivArr[num] + " ";
        mainDiv.innerHTML = "";
        spanArr.push(span);
        num++;
      } else if (placeHolderArr[num].trim() !== mainDivArr[num].trim()) {
        const span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.color = "red";
        span.textContent = mainDivArr[num] + " ";
        mainDiv.innerHTML = "";
        spanArr.push(span);
        num++;
      }

      for (let spans of spanArr) {
        mainDiv.innerHTML += spans.outerHTML;
        //    Placing Caret At The End
        function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
          el.focus();
          if (
            typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
            typeof document.createRange != "undefined"
          ) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            range.collapse(false);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
          } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(el);
            textRange.collapse(false);
            textRange.select();
          }
        }
        placeCaretAtEnd(mainDiv);
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log("space pressed");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
  width: 70vw;
}

#mainDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="mainDiv" autofocus contenteditable></div>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan please take a look at the question again i edited it and added the code

Comment: TO optimize it simply place the entire `function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {` in the root scope.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan done that but no results same slow performance

Comment: Well, that was only one improvement :D The other one would be not using for loop inside for loop. And the third one would be to change completely the approach - since the one you currently use is too buggy anyways.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan WHAT TYPE OF BUGS ? Any New recommendations about approach?

Comment: Well, it depends. Are you trying to recreate an app like https://type.fit ? For words only? The other suggestion would be to have three DIV elements, one with the original placeholder text. The other with the colored SPAN words and the third one with the text the user types but with transparent text and with a visible caret.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no like monkeytype.com

Comment: well, neither there you can move the caret. You can only continue to type...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan but how can i improve the typing speed as the monkeytype.com will also have huge js code and tell me a course related to improving the code speed

Comment: On every keystroke you're rerunning the heavy for loops. One idea would be to rethink your approach into achieving something like monkeytype.com. In your example - as soon you miss some characters there's no way to get back in track with the placeholder text. The text you type, even if correct will no longer overlap correctly. So yea, you took the wrong approach I'm afraid.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ok I learned one thing now running a long code after every second can make the website slow. So i think a new approach and please give me a suggestion about it the new approch is not running this huge amount of code on every key event but what i will do i will track what user type the word and i will match only that word and instead of appending the whole span list i will only append the new word user type in the div with contenteditabe  attribute. I think it will work what you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider another approach to the problem.
Instead of doing heavy operations over a contenteditable, disrupting such an area *while* the user is inserting text / typing, using two nested heavy for loops (O(n^2) complexity), and defining functions within a for loop (all really bad practices), I would suggest:

- use only one DIV element
- populate it with SPANs for words and characters
- set it as `tabindex="1"` so that you can focus it and capture keyboard events
- create an index variable `idx` so you can keep track on the progress and add classes to every character SPAN
- on `"keydown"` event, use `Event.key` to determine the pressed key character. If the character matches with the current expected character, advance the `index`

```js
const text = `Focus and start typing. Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.`;
const elText = document.querySelector("#text");
const textChars = [];
const words = text.split(/(?<=\S+\s)/g);

// Create SPAN for words and characters
elText.innerHTML = words.reduce((html, word) => {
  textChars.push(...word);
  const chars = [...word].map(ch => `<span class="char">${ch}</span>`).join("");
  return html + `<span class="word">${chars}</span>`;
}, "");

const elsChars = elText.querySelectorAll(".char");
const totChars = textChars.length;
let totIncorrect = 0;
let isGameOver = false;
let idx = 0; // type progress index
elsChars[idx].classList.add("current");

elText.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {

  if (isGameOver) return; // Prevent any more typing
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent spacebar scrolling etc...

  let typeChar = ev.key;
  if (typeChar === "Enter") typeChar = " "; // Treat Enter as Space
  if (typeChar.length > 1) return; // Do nothing on special keys

  // CORRECT:
  if (typeChar === textChars[idx]) {
    elsChars[idx].classList.add("ok");
  }
  // INCORRECT:
  else {
    elsChars[idx].classList.add("err");
    totIncorrect += 1;
  }
  
  // ADVANCE:
  elsChars[idx].classList.remove("current");
  idx += 1;
  elsChars[idx]?.classList.add("current");
  
  // GAME OVER:
  if (idx === totChars) {
    isGameOver = true;
    console.log(`Well done! You had ${totIncorrect} mistakes out of ${totChars}!`);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font: 1.5rem/1.3 sans-serif;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: grey;
  width: 60vw;
  color: #888;
  letter-spacing: 0.15rem;
}

#text:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.char {
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#text:focus .current {
  animation: blink 1s infinite; 
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {box-shadow: -3px 0 0 #000;}
  50% {box-shadow: -3px 0 0 #000;}
  100% {box-shadow: -3px 0 0 transparent;}
}

.ok {
  color: #000;
  background: hsla(200 , 100%, 50%, 0.1);
}

.err {
  color: #f00;
  background: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="text" tabindex="1"></div>
```

With this simpler solution, now you can type as fast as it goes :)
For mobile devices you could incorporate an overlay transparent textarea in order to grab focus and prompt the onscreen keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Its helpful but one question like I now started the frontend development and was working on this problem for last 2 days and you solved this just in a half day how ? is it take time to learn the coding skills you have now or with time coding skills become better

Comment: 25min != 12h :)  I got a hint by looking at the source HTML of the page you suggested. Then I knew how to write the CSS and JS. Imagine development as putting Lego pieces together. If you know by heart all your pieces in your box, and you know which ones fit together, you'll build everything you want pretty quickly. I know all my pieces pretty well, so I guess it's pure experience. And I never stop *buying* new pieces :) I'd suggest you to build as often as you can. Enjoy. (PS, if you have questions about this solution and the code, feel free to ask).

Comment: So do you also watch courses or you read documentation can please provide me some references which you use when you want to revise or want to revisit everything you learned and in the above comment where you tell me that if you know by heart all your pieces in your box you mean knowledge ? btw very good advice you gave me thanks